# How to create a link with an absolute path in Linux?

Tags: linux, sh, symlink

By using "ln -s a b", it creates a soft-link from b to a with a relative path. If 'b' is moved to another directory, it would get broken.

Is there any way so I can create an link with an absolute path?

Comment: Use the absolute path?

Comment: This question belongs on [Superuser](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: Also, do that in your terminal `man ln`. It will save you many headaches in the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply use the full path to the link target:

```
ln -s /full/path/to/a b
```

Comment: To get full path, use "readlink -f". Put simply:
```ln -s `readlink -f a` b```